# Page not found (404) Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/login

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

I already posted this error but I couldn't find an answer, now I'm reposting with more details of my code.

I'm new in coding field.
I decided to start a project with Django & Python, but I got stuck due to some errors. For the past 3 weeks, I tried to figure out what was the issue but couldn't find it.
Please help me to figure out the problems.

I have **3 problems**:
**1-Welcome Page

2-Login & Registration(Sign-up)

3-Seach part**

**1.Welcome Page** 
Welcome Page is the first page.
It's the first page that any users see whenever he comes to the website and it is also a page where he has to login if he want to go to the second page.
**PROBLEM 1**:\ whenever I get to the website, I won't see the content of the first page which is the welcome page.
It will take me directly to the second page without even login

**2- Login & Registration(Sign-up)**:
Before getting into the second  web page, The user has to login. If he can't login, he has to register.
After registering, he will be redirected to the login page.
**PROBLEM 2**:\ When I'm trying to Login, I received the message saying the page not found.

**3- Search part**:
After getting into the second page,  we have a search bar where whenever the user wants to search a  product, he has just to type the name of the product and get back the list  of the product he is looking for in case there are many products in the database.
**PROBLEM 3**:\ When I type the name of the product in the search bar, it does show any list of the product.

Thanks in advance

Problem 2:**The Login Error**

```
**Page not found** (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/login
Using the URLconf defined in grouppublishingindia.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
register_request [name='register_request']
login_request [name='login_request']
logout_request [name='logout_request']
SearchResultsView [name='search_results']
^$ [name='index']
^WelcomePage/$ [name='welcomepage']
^display_Rocky_Railway$ [name='display_Rocky_Railway']
^display_Roar$ [name='display_Roar']
^display_Shipwreched$ [name='display_Shipwreched']
^display_FWN1$ [name='display_FWN1']
^display_FWN2$ [name='display_FWN2']
^display_FWN3$ [name='display_FWN3']
^display_LIFE_OF_JESUS$ [name='display_LIFE_OF_JESUS']
^display_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story$ [name='display_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story']
^add_Rocky_Railway$ [name='add_Rocky_Railway']
^add_Roar$ [name='add_Roar']
^add_Shipwreched$ [name='add_Shipwreched']
^add_FWN1$ [name='add_FWN1']
^add_FWN2$ [name='add_FWN2']
^add_FWN3$ [name='add_FWN3']
^add_LIFE_OF_JESUS$ [name='add_LIFE_OF_JESUS']
^add_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story$ [name='add_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story']
^edit_Rocky_Railway/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='edit_Rocky_Railway']
^edit_Roar/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='edit_Roar']
^edit_Shipwreched/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='edit_Shipwreched']
^edit_FWN1/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='edit_FWN1']
^edit_FWN2/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='edit_FWN2']
^edit_FWN3/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='edit_FWN3']
^edit_LIFE_OF_JESUS/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='edit_LIFE_OF_JESUS']
^edit_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='edit_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story']
^delete_Rocky_Railway/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='delete_Rocky_Railway']
^delete_Roar/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='delete_Roar']
^delete_Shipwreched/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='delete_Shipwreched']
^delete_FWN1/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='delete_FWN1']
^delete_FWN2/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='delete_FWN2']
^delete_FWN3/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='delete_FWN3']
^delete_LIFE_OF_JESUS/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='delete_LIFE_OF_JESUS']
^delete_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story/(?P<pk>\d+)$ [name='delete_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story']
^Inventory/
The current path, login, didn't match any of these.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Problem 1 & 3 are described above.

This is my Welcome page content Page

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
  <h1>Welcome To GROUP INDIA INVENTORY</h1>
{% endblock %}


My URLs from the Project(grouppublishingindia):

   from django.urls import path, include
   from django.conf.urls import url
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.conf import settings
   from Inventory import views

   urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("",include("Inventory.urls")),
    url(r"^Inventory/",include('django.contrib.auth.urls'))
]
```

My URLs from the Application(Inventory):

```
  from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
   from django.urls import reverse
   from django.conf.urls import url
   from .views import *
   from Inventory import views
   from .views import index
   from Inventory.views import SearchResultsView
   from django.urls import path

    app_name = "Inventory"

    urlpatterns =[


    path("register_request", views.register_request, name="register_request"),
    path("login_request", views.login_request, name="login_request"),
    path("logout_request", views.logout_request, name= "logout_request"),


    path('SearchResultsView', SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search_results'),

    #url(r'Login/$', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="templates/registration/login.html"),name="login"),
    #url(r'Logout/$', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(),name="logout"),
    #url(r'SignUp/$', views.SignUp.as_view(template_name = "templates/registration/signup.html"),name="signup"),

    url(r"^$", index, name="index"),

    url(r'^WelcomePage/$', WelcomePage.as_view(template_name = "Welcome_Page.html"), name="welcomepage"),


    url(r"^display_Rocky_Railway$", display_Rocky_Railway, name='display_Rocky_Railway'),
    url(r"^display_Roar$", display_Roar, name='display_Roar'),
    url(r"^display_Shipwreched$", display_Shipwreched, name='display_Shipwreched'),
    url(r"^display_FWN1$", display_FWN1, name='display_FWN1'),
    url(r"^display_FWN2$", display_FWN2, name='display_FWN2'),
    url(r"^display_FWN3$", display_FWN3, name='display_FWN3'),
    url(r"^display_LIFE_OF_JESUS$", display_LIFE_OF_JESUS, name='display_LIFE_OF_JESUS'),
    url(r"^display_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story$", display_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story, name='display_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story'),

    url(r"^add_Rocky_Railway$", add_Rocky_Railway, name='add_Rocky_Railway'),
    url(r"^add_Roar$", add_Roar, name='add_Roar'),
    url(r"^add_Shipwreched$", add_Shipwreched, name='add_Shipwreched'),
    url(r"^add_FWN1$", add_FWN1, name='add_FWN1'),
    url(r"^add_FWN2$", add_FWN2, name='add_FWN2'),
    url(r"^add_FWN3$", add_FWN3, name='add_FWN3'),
    url(r"^add_LIFE_OF_JESUS$", add_LIFE_OF_JESUS, name='add_LIFE_OF_JESUS'),
    url(r"^add_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story$", add_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story, name='add_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story'),

    url(r"^edit_Rocky_Railway/(?P<pk>\d+)$", edit_Rocky_Railway, name='edit_Rocky_Railway'),
    url(r"^edit_Roar/(?P<pk>\d+)$", edit_Roar, name='edit_Roar'),
    url(r"^edit_Shipwreched/(?P<pk>\d+)$", edit_Shipwreched, name='edit_Shipwreched'),
    url(r"^edit_FWN1/(?P<pk>\d+)$", edit_FWN1, name='edit_FWN1'),
    url(r"^edit_FWN2/(?P<pk>\d+)$", edit_FWN2, name='edit_FWN2'),
    url(r"^edit_FWN3/(?P<pk>\d+)$", edit_FWN3, name='edit_FWN3'),
    url(r"^edit_LIFE_OF_JESUS/(?P<pk>\d+)$", edit_LIFE_OF_JESUS, name='edit_LIFE_OF_JESUS'),
    url(r"^edit_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story/(?P<pk>\d+)$", edit_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story, name='edit_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story'),

    url(r"^delete_Rocky_Railway/(?P<pk>\d+)$", delete_Rocky_Railway, name='delete_Rocky_Railway'),
    url(r"^delete_Roar/(?P<pk>\d+)$", delete_Roar, name='delete_Roar'),
    url(r"^delete_Shipwreched/(?P<pk>\d+)$", delete_Shipwreched, name='delete_Shipwreched'),
    url(r"^delete_FWN1/(?P<pk>\d+)$", delete_FWN1, name='delete_FWN1'),
    url(r"^delete_FWN2/(?P<pk>\d+)$", delete_FWN2, name='delete_FWN2'),
    url(r"^delete_FWN3/(?P<pk>\d+)$", delete_FWN3, name='delete_FWN3'),
    url(r"^delete_LIFE_OF_JESUS/(?P<pk>\d+)$", delete_LIFE_OF_JESUS, name='delete_LIFE_OF_JESUS'),
    url(r"^delete_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story/(?P<pk>\d+)$", delete_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story, name='delete_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story'),

]
```

The place where my welcome page, search page, login page and register page are calling from (Views.py):

```
   from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
   from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
   from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
   from django.views.generic import TemplateView
   from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
   from django.urls import reverse_lazy
   from django.views.generic import CreateView
   from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
   from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
   from .models import *
   from .forms import *
   from Inventory import forms
   from django.db.models import Q
   from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
   from .forms import NewUserForm
   from django.contrib import messages
   from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm


   #Index
     def index(request):
       return render(request,'index.html')

   #Register(signup)
     def register_request(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
          form = NewUserForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
              user = form.save()
              login(request, user)
              messages.success(request, "Registration successful." )
              return redirect("index")
          messages.error(request, "Unsuccessful registration. Invalid information.")
      form = NewUserForm
      return render (request=request, template_name="register_request.html", context= 
  {"register_form":form})


   #Login
   def login_request(request):
       if request.method == "POST":
           form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
           if form.is_valid():
               username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
               password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
               user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
               if user is not None:
                   login(request, user)
                   messages.info(request, "You are now logged in as {username}.")
                   return redirect("index")
               else:
                   messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
           else:
               messages.error(request,"Invalid username or password.")
       form = AuthenticationForm()
       return render(request=request, template_name="login_request.html", context={"login_form":form})


   #Logout
      def logout_request(request):
       logout(request)
       messages.info(request, "You have successfully logged out.")
       return redirect("welcomepage")

def delete_FWN3(request, pk):
    Product.objects.filter(id=pk).delete()
    items = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'items': items
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)

def delete_LIFE_OF_JESUS(request, pk):
    Product.objects.filter(id=pk).delete()
    items = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'items': items
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)


def delete_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story(request, pk):
    Product.objects.filter(id=pk).delete()
    items = Product.objects.all()
    context = {
        'items': items
    }
    return render(request,'index.html',context)

class WelcomePage(TemplateView):
    template_name = "Welcome_Page.html"

def register(response):
    if response.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreateForm(response.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

        return redirect("login_request")
    else:
        form = UserCreateForm()

    return render(response, 'Inventory/register.html', {"form":form})

#search

class SearchResultsView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "search_results.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('q')
        object_list = Product.objects.filter(
            Q(Sales__icontains=query) | Q(Product__icontains=query)
            )
        return object_list

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['query'] = self.request.GET.get('q')
        return context
```

My Settings:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '5r0zcv0wdd2yhow_t)k)xj$c(3mnkqiww_yr0w7k+i+ii36)5v'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'crispy_forms',
    'debug_toolbar',
    'Inventory',
    'import_export',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware'
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'grouppublishingindia.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'grouppublishingindia.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

My Login page HTML content:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!--Login-->
<div class="container py-5">
  <h1>Login</h1>
  <form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ login_form|crispy }}
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Login</button>
  </form>
  <p class="text-center">Don't have an account? <a href="/register_request">Create an account</a>.</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My Register page content:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!--Register-->
<div class="container py-5">
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ register_form|crispy }}
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Register</button>
    </form>
    <p class="text-center">If you already have an account, <a href="/login_request">login</a> instead.</p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

My search html page content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>search results</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      {% for product in object_list %}
      <li>
        {{ product.Product}}
      </li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

My Models.py content

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):

    def __str__(self):
        return "@{}".format(self.username)

class Category (models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class Product (models.Model):
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="products", null=True)
    Product = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False)
    Total_Produced = models.IntegerField()
    Sales = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Total_Available = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    objects = models.Manager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Product

    @property
    def Save(self):
        return self.Total_Produced - self.Sales

class Rocky_Railway(models.Model):
    Product = models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=False)
    Total_Produced = models.IntegerField()
    Sales = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Total_Available = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Product:{0} Total_Produced:{1} Sales:{2} Total_Available:{3} '.format(self.Product, self.Total_Produced, self.Sales, self.Total_Available)

class Roar(Rocky_Railway):
    pass

class Shipwreched(Rocky_Railway):
    pass

class FWN1(Rocky_Railway):
    pass

class FWN2(Rocky_Railway):
    pass

class FWN3(Rocky_Railway):
    pass

class LIFE_OF_JESUS(Rocky_Railway):
    pass

class Leader_Manuals(Rocky_Railway):
    pass

class Student_Books(Rocky_Railway):
    pass

class Friends_with_God_Bible_Story(Rocky_Railway):
    pass
```

My Index page content:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block body %}
<br>
<div class="jumbotron text-center">


    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:display_Rocky_Railway' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="padding:10px 20px; font-size:20px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">ROCKY RAILWAY</a>

    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:display_Roar' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="padding:10px 20px; font-size:20px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">ROAR</a>

    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:display_Shipwreched' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="padding:10px 20px; font-size:20px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">SHIPWRECKED</a>

    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:display_FWN1' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="padding:10px 20px; font-size:20px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">FWN1</a>

    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:display_FWN2' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="padding:10px 20px; font-size:20px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">FWN2</a>

    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:display_FWN3' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="padding:10px 20px; font-size:20px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">FWN3</a>

    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:display_LIFE_OF_JESUS' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="padding:10px 20px; font-size:20px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">LIFE OF JESUS</a>

    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:display_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story' %}" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" role="button" style="padding:10px 20px; font-size:20px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">FRIENDS WITH GOD BIBLE STORY</a>
    <a href="{% url 'Inventory:add_Rocky_Railway' %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button" style="padding:4px 20px; font-size:30px; font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">+</a>

  <br>
  <br>
    <h6 style="font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">Currently Viewing {{header}}</h6>
  <br>

    <table class="table table-blue text-center" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>PRODUCT</th>
          <th>TOTAL PRODUCED</th>
          <th>SALES</th>
          <th>TOTAL AVAILABLE</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

      {% for item in items %}
        <tr>
          <td style="font:Adobe Garamond Pro Bold">{{ item.pk }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Product }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Total_Produced }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Sales }}</td>
          <td>{{ item.Save }}</td>

          {% if header == "Rocky_Railway" %}
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:edit_Rocky_Railway' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:delete_Rocky_Railway' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">X</a>
          </td>

          {% elif header == "Roar" %}
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:edit_Roar' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:delete_Roar' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">X</a>
          </td>

          {% elif header == "Shipwreched" %}
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:edit_Shipwreched' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:delete_Shipwreched' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">X</a>
          </td>

          {% elif header == "FWN1" %}
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:edit_FWN1' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:delete_FWN1' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">X</a>
          </td>

          {% elif header == "FWN2" %}
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:edit_FWN2' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:delete_FWN2' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">X</a>
          </td>

          {% elif header == "FWN3" %}
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:edit_FWN3' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:delete_FWN3' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">X</a>
          </td>

          {% elif header == "LIFE_OF_JESUS" %}
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:edit_LIFE_OF_JESUS' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:delete_LIFE_OF_JESUS' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">X</a>
          </td>

          {% else %}
          <td>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:edit_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" role="button">Edit</a>
            <a href="{% url 'Inventory:delete_Friends_with_God_Bible_Story' item.pk %}" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" role="button">X</a>
          </td>
          {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
  </table>


</div>


{% endblock %}
```

My root from:

```
C:\User\Badgira\Documents\PythonProject\Projects\
                                        |               
                                        |
                                grouppublishingindia\
                                        |
                                        |
                                     templates\
                                        |
                                        |
                                    Welcome_Page
                                        |
                                    login_request
                                        |
                                     register
                                        |
                                   search_results
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you have no path defined for ".../login" so you can not use this url or you get the error.
2. "whenever I get to the website" ... what does this mean? When you go to 127.0.0.1:8000/ ?  According to your urls.py this should call index. Is that what you expect? If you want the welcome page to show you need to remove:

```
url(r"^$", index, name="index"),
```

and add something like

```
path("", WelcomePage.as_view(template.....), name="welcomepage")
```

3. what do you mean with "second page"? Which url/view do you refere to?
4. in none if your html code I can find something like a "search bar" what do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi @Razenstein,
2- Yes, when I go to 127.0.0.1:800/, the welcome page should be the first-page showing. But I'm not able to see that.
3- I refer to my Index page, you can have a look, I added the code